# How to move the elements of a list view by dragging them MAUI

Tags: c#, maui, visual-studio-2022, maui-windows

I have a list of ViewCell containing an image and two labels. I have to be able to select an element and move it above or below to change the position to the element, so that you can customize the position of the elements on the list.
The Listview is a link to an ObSustacollection that gets the elemners when you enter the page.
I tried to replicate this question with the drag and drop but I can't get the same desired result.

I would like to be able to move the elements of the list freely, even with some faces effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the original ListView or CollectionView, you can not move the elements by dragging them manually. But you can check this link about the [CollectionView Drag & Drop Item Reordering Spec](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3767). The auther provide a Nuget package to achieve the effect you want.

Comment: I had already seen this package but I couln't use it because I use c#7 and it's for c#6.

Comment: That nuget package is not suitable for the .net7. But I found that you can use the `DragGestureRecognizer` to achieve this effect. You can refer to this [How to use drag and drop gesture to CollectionView in MAUI](https://learnmobiledevelopment.com/index.php/2023/01/14/drag-and-drop-gesture-to-collectionview/).

Comment: I have the problem whit the scrolling. Bucause i have a big list and when i do the drag, the list view / collection view doesnt scroll automaticaly

Comment: It only provides the method to drag the item up and down. You can check the [Control scrolling in a CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/scrolling?view=net-maui-7.0).

Comment: I had seen that you could put checks for scrolling, but I noticed that if I am making the drag not activate the scrolling event. After Hon did the drop then the event is activated. Do you know how I can ensure that both events will go simultaneously ??. Because if I use the mouse wheel then everything works, if instead I use the arrow to move on it or below I can't scroll through the ListView/ CollectionView

Comment: it is not supported that you use the mouse to control the collectionview scroll. You can check this thread about [Desktop platforms: Mouse and Keyboard classes or DependencyServices](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3739) for more information.